# Django ORM Query Optimization Issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I am making a blog website and I am facing some issues with the Query performance.

I have 3 models

1. User Model -> Users (To store user email, Password etc)
2. Post Model -> Actual Posts
3. people Model -> (To store users extra information)

Post Model ->

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)   
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    Likes = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='Post_likes')
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(to=User,blank=True,related_name="favourite")
```

People Model ->

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True,null=True)
    Phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    Birth_Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now as both of these models are connected to User model. I want to query the Post model and get the user photo in the template. Now when I use `post.user.people.photo` then for every post it generates a seperate query to DB resulting in slowness. I would like to use Join here to combines multiple tables and fetch all the records at once.

I am currently using following Query ->

```
posts =  Post.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('images_set').annotate(comments_Count = Count('comments_post',distinct=True)).annotate(Count('Likes',distinct=True)).all().order_by('-id')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) on the `user` and the `people` with `user__people`, so:

```
posts = Post.objects.select_related(
    'user__people', 'category'
).prefetch_related('images_set').annotate(
    comments_Count = Count('comments_post',distinct=True),
    Count('Likes',distinct=True)
).order_by('-id')
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).